# LINQ to XML: What is the most effective way to move nodes up and down

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to move sibling nodes before and after certain nodes. Here is the code im working with

```
<tabs>
     <tab>
          <name>Overview</name>
     </tab>
     <tab>
          <name>Testing</name>
     </tab>
     <tab>
          <name>Performance</name>
     </tab>
     <tab>
          <name>Braking</name>
     </tab>
</tabs>
```

I would like to move the tab with testing in it above Overview. How would I go about this using linq to XML?

Comment: What are the rules for which sibling node is moved before/after which node? Or are you just asking how to move nodes around?

Comment: That is exactly what I need. I need to know how to move nodes around. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is VB.NET and XML Literals, but it can be done old school in C#. The idea here is to use the `Reverse` extention method:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim tab = <tabs>
                      <tab>
                          <name>Overview</name>
                      </tab>
                      <tab>
                          <name>Testing</name>
                      </tab>
                      <tab>
                          <name>Performance</name>
                      </tab>
                      <tab>
                          <name>Braking</name>
                      </tab>
                  </tabs>
        Console.WriteLine(SwapElements("Testing", "Performance", tab).ToString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    Function SwapElements(ByVal firstElement As String, ByVal secondElement As String, ByVal tab As XElement) As XElement
        Dim swapped = tab.Elements.Where(Function(e) e.Value = firstElement Or e.Value = secondElement).Reverse
        Dim middle = tab.Elements.SelectMany(Function(e) e.ElementsAfterSelf.Where(Function(f) e.Value = firstElement).TakeWhile(Function(g) g.Value <> secondElement))
        swapped.ElementAt(0).AddAfterSelf(middle)
        Return <<%= tab.Name %>>
                   <%= tab.Elements.Select(Function(e) e.ElementsBeforeSelf.Where(Function(f) e.Value = firstElement)) %>
                   <%= swapped %>
                   <%= tab.Elements.Select(Function(e) e.ElementsAfterSelf.Where(Function(f) e.Value = secondElement)) %>
               </>
    End Function
```

Comment: wow..after reading this several times I see that this is the most elegant way of solving this problem. Sorry I have already choosen the answer. I have implemented your solution instead. Thank you

Comment: What if the two elements are not adjacent to each other?

Comment: @dtb: Then you'd need more code. Query for all after `firstElement` and all before `secondElement` and do a `.Add` to `swapped`. I've updated the code above with 2 lines of code to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You can move the elements by removing them and then reinserting them at the desired position:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<tabs>...</tabs>");

var tab = doc.Root.Elements().ElementAt(1);
tab.Remove();
doc.Root.AddFirst(tab);
```

Alternatively, you can create a new document from the existing elements in the desired order:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<tabs>...</tabs>");

var tabs = doc.Root.Elements();

var result = new XDocument(
                 new XElement("tabs", 
                     tabs.ElementAt(1),
                     tabs.ElementAt(0),
                     tabs.ElementAt(2)));
```

---

I haven't tested it, but this might work:

```
void Swap(XElement a, XElement b)
{
    var c = new XElement("dummy");
    a.ReplaceWith(c);
    b.ReplaceWith(a);
    c.ReplaceWith(b);
}
```

Comment: I am really not interested in moving nodes to the first or last position I simply want to swap nodes. How would I swap Testing and Performance if the current tab is Testing?

Comment: Also, your example assumes I know how many siblings there are? If I don't know how many siblings there are but i know the Testing element exists somewhere in the siblings how would I swap these elements?

Comment: @Luke101: I've added a solution to swap to arbitrary XElements in an XDocument. I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
    var tests = from node in doc.Descendants("name") where node.Value == "Testing" select node;
    var test = tests.Single();
    var tab = test.Parent;
    var tabs = tab.Parent;
    tab.Remove();
    tabs.AddFirst(tab);
```

Not sure how much of your XML structure is fixed / known.

Comment: I believe this code moves testing to the first position. Now how would I move swap Testing and performance? i am really not interesting in moving nodes to the firat or last place i simply want to swap nodes. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I came up with the same issue today and end up resolving it this way:

```
private void SwapXNodes(bool up, int inUniqueID)
    {
        XElement currNode = DocumentManager.xMainDocument.XPathSelectElement("//*[@UniqueID='" + inUniqueID + "']"); // find 

        if (up)
        {
            if (currNode.PreviousNode != null)
            {
                XElement xPrevious = new XElement((XElement)currNode.PreviousNode); // copy of previous node

                currNode.PreviousNode.ReplaceWith(currNode); // previous node equal to me
                currNode.ReplaceWith(xPrevious); // Now I should be equal to previous node
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (currNode.NextNode != null)
            {
                XElement xNext = new XElement((XElement)currNode.NextNode); // copy of Next node

                currNode.NextNode.ReplaceWith(currNode); // Next node equal to me
                currNode.ReplaceWith(xNext); // Now I should be equal to Next node copy
            }
        }
    }
```